# Purr's best functions to conditionally select some columns and apply some function to its content

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like, using purr, to conditionally select some columns and then to apply a function to all the elements of these selected columns.

```
> glimpse(iris)
Rows: 150
Columns: 5
$ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4,...
$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9,...
$ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4,...
$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2,...
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, seto...
```

Let's say I would like to **replace all values** from each numerical column **with the mean of its respective column** (thus keeping the same dataframe structure with 150 rows and 5 columns. Using this code simply creates a list with one mean per column.

```
iris %>% 
  map_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
  glimpse()
```

Such as

```
List of 5
 $ Sepal.Length: num 5.84
 $ Sepal.Width : num 3.06
 $ Petal.Length: num 3.76
 $ Petal.Width : num 1.2
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",...
```

I tried using a second map function, for instance this:

```
iris %>% 
  map_if(is.numeric, map(~{mean(.x)}) %>%
  glimpse()
```

But of course this doesn't work, probably because I don't specify the atomic vector/list to map. I have also tried to use map_depth but I'm not sure this is appropriate. I know I could probably use mutate_at or something similar but I would like to have a better understand of purr's functions !

Update if it wasn't so clear:

```
iris %>% 
  map_if(is.numeric, ~{.x * 20}) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

This returns a multiplication by 20 of each element of each column that is numerical. However what I'd like to do is access the "whole column mean" instead of only being able to modify element by element (.x). That's probably a syntax issue that I'm not aware of.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding purrr with map_at() would not be the best solution because it applies a function to the column and gives a list as a result. When using a grouping function (such as mean(), sum(), etc.) the result will be one value instead of one for each row.

Though since you have a non numerical column you can make it work anyhow as R will recycle values to fill up the data.frame/tibble:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  purrr::map_if(is.numeric, ~ mean(.x)) %>%
  dplyr::as_tibble()

 # A tibble: 150 x 5
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 2         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 3         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 4         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 5         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 6         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 7         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 8         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 9         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
10         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa
```

This can be adaped as well to use the mean for a calculation per value:

```
iris %>% 
  map_if(is.numeric, ~ mean(.x) + .x) %>%
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1         10.9        6.56         5.16        1.40 setosa 
 2         10.7        6.06         5.16        1.40 setosa 
 3         10.5        6.26         5.06        1.40 setosa 
 4         10.4        6.16         5.26        1.40 setosa 
 5         10.8        6.66         5.16        1.40 setosa 
 6         11.2        6.96         5.46        1.60 setosa 
 7         10.4        6.46         5.16        1.50 setosa 
 8         10.8        6.46         5.26        1.40 setosa 
 9         10.2        5.96         5.16        1.40 setosa 
10         10.7        6.16         5.26        1.30 setosa
```

As you mentioned mutate() from dplyr would be the better solutino from my understanding:

```
iris %>% 
  dplyr::as_tibble() %>% # not necessariy but guaranties an output as above
  dplyr::mutate(across(is.numeric, ~mean(.x)))

# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 2         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 3         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 4         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 5         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 6         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 7         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 8         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
 9         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa 
10         5.84        3.06         3.76        1.20 setosa
```

Now we can do the same calculation per row as before with the second purrr::map_if()

```
iris %>% 
  dplyr::as_tibble() %>% # not necessariy but guaranties an output as above
  dplyr::mutate(across(is.numeric, ~mean(.x) + .x))

# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1         10.9        6.56         5.16        1.40 setosa 
 2         10.7        6.06         5.16        1.40 setosa 
 3         10.5        6.26         5.06        1.40 setosa 
 4         10.4        6.16         5.26        1.40 setosa 
 5         10.8        6.66         5.16        1.40 setosa 
 6         11.2        6.96         5.46        1.60 setosa 
 7         10.4        6.46         5.16        1.50 setosa 
 8         10.8        6.46         5.26        1.40 setosa 
 9         10.2        5.96         5.16        1.40 setosa 
10         10.7        6.16         5.26        1.30 setosa
```

I hope this answers your question?!